# How to set datatype of this in vue in typescript?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

In typescript + vue2, I define a vue instance like this

```
new Vue({
    ...
    data : {
      a:"test"
    },
    methods: {
        func1() {
            alert(this.a); // this is type any
            this.func2();   // this is type any
        },
        func2() {
        }
    }
});
```

In VS code, it tells me that this is type `any` which means I can't get type checking with the reactive props, methods, computed, etc...

How can I set it up to get full type checking?

Comment: You won't get full type checking this way, especially since you don't use a separate component. Use composition api. One of reasons it exists is that options api is poorly suitable for TS by design

Comment: But I am using vue 2 and can't switch to 3 yet

Comment: Vue 2.7 supports composition. And there's `@vue/composition` for earlier versions

Comment: @omega I cannot reproduce the issue in Vue 2.6 or 2.7 with the code you've posted.

Comment: @omega I stand corrected, this is 100% VSCode problem, it's incorrect to ask the question in general. it will behave differently during a build. This is specific to IDE and plugin versions that you use. No matter how bad Vue TS support is, `this` shouldn't be `any` in a method